# Unable to retrieve messages from Queue in Python Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

I would like to receive the events in my thread which will be further responsible for invoking the sensor. Events are generated in `client.py` and sensor is controlled by `TemperatureSensorThread`. My problem is - I am not able to get the value out from the queue in Thread. I have tried both `queue.Queue` and `multiprocessing.Queue` but both didn't work.

I am not sure what is missing.

**TemperatureSensorThread.py**

```
from threading import Thread
from src.sensor import PowerSetting, TemperatureSensor
from multiprocessing import Queue

class TemperatureSensorThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, q: Queue):
        super().__init__()
        # Thread.init(self)
        self.sensor = TemperatureSensor('temperature_sensor')
        self.q = q
        self.last_temp = -1
        self.last_pow_setting = PowerSetting.POWER_OFF

    def run(self) -> None:
        should_continue = True
        while should_continue:
            print(f'Thread is {self.isAlive()}')
            message: dict = self.q.get()
            print(f'Queue message\t{message}')
            _action = message.get('action')
            _temp = message.get('temp')

            sensor_temp = self.last_temp  
            pow_setting = self.last_pow_setting 
            if _action == 'exit':
                # Exit CS
                should_continue = False
                break

            sensor_temp = self.last_temp if _temp is None else _temp
            pow_setting = PowerSetting.POWER_ON if _action == 'start' else PowerSetting.POWER_OFF

            self.sensor.set_temperature(sensor_temp)
            self.sensor.turn_on_off(power_setting=pow_setting)

            self.last_pow_setting = pow_setting
            self.last_temp = sensor_temp
```

**Client.py**

```
from src.temperature_sensor_thread import TemperatureSensorThread
from multiprocessing import Queue
import time

temp_q: Queue = Queue()

t = TemperatureSensorThread(q=temp_q)
t.start()
print('Setting temp 32')
temp_q.put({'temp': 32})

print('Action: START')
temp_q.put({'action': 'start'})
time.sleep(4)

print('Action: STOP')
temp_q.put({'action': 'stop'})
time.sleep(3)

print('Temp: 41')
temp_q.put({'temp': 41})
time.sleep(3)

print('Action: START')
temp_q.put({'action': 'start'})
time.sleep(3)

print('Action: Exit')
temp_q.put({'action': 'exit'})
time.sleep(5)
print('Code exit')
```

Comment: Why are you using a multiprocessing.Queue instead of a queue.Queue?  The former is designed for multiple processes, which you don't have.  The queue.Queue class is for multiple threads, which is what you have.  I don't know for a fact that multiprocessing.Queue won't work here; but your program isn't working so it would seem like the first thing to try.  Also, please tell us what your program actually does.  You have print statements in there - what do you see when you run your program?

Comment: Sorry I missed your statement that you tried both types of Queue.  It would still be nice to know what printout you see.

Comment: In Python3.10, Thread objects do not have a method `isAlive`.  The correct name is `is_alive`.  Earlier versions of Python may have had this function name.  The thread will crash on the first print statement.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there are no exceptions arising within then thread. Here's a cut-back example that works perfectly in 3.10.5

Note the mechanism used to shutdown the thread - i.e., just put None on the queue

```
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Queue

class Sensor(Thread):
    def __init__(self, q):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = q
    def run(self):
        while (d := self.q.get()):
            print(d)

q = Queue()
s = Sensor(q)
s.start()
q.put({'temp': 32})
q.put({'action': 'start'})
q.put(None)
s.join()
print('Done')
```

**Output:**

```
{'temp': 32}
{'action': 'start'}
Done
```

Comment: Well this works for me as well, but i still can't spot any kind of exception in the thread for my code.